# preconditions for properties of a std::span that could be static or dynamic

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a function that is generic over the extent of a std::span it receives as a parameter. I want to do some checks on it as efficiently as possible while avoiding duplication but guaranteeing a compile error when it's possible.

My goal is to:

1. Error as early as possible, always at compile time when possible.
2. Generate a good error message at compile time (static assert failure with file and line number), and at runtime in debug builds (assertion error with file and line number), but have the minimal required overhead in release builds.
3. Have zero runtime overhead if checked at compile time. If the runtime check is included it should have an optimization hint in release configuration.

For example, I have the following function that does preflight checks on a `std::span` before passing its raw contents to a fast implementation that does no checks. Since it's templated on span's Extent parameter I can sometimes do these checks at compile time. The problem is that leads me to repeat the precondition `pairs.size() > 0 && pairs.size() % 2 == 0` three times, depending on whether I am using `static_assert`, `assert`, or a cheap release mode runtime check:

```cpp
#include <span>
#ifndef NDEBUG
#include <cassert>
#endif

extern long SumOfDistancesFast(const long *, size_t) noexcept;

template<size_t Extent = std::dynamic_extent>
[[nodiscard]]
constexpr long SumOfDistances(std::span<const long, Extent> pairs) noexcept
{
    static_assert(Extent == decltype(pairs)::extent);
    if constexpr (Extent != std::dynamic_extent) {
        static_assert(pairs.size() == Extent);
        static_assert(pairs.size() > 0 && pairs.size() % 2 == 0);
    } else {
#ifdef NDEBUG
        if (!(pairs.size() > 0 && pairs.size() % 2 == 0)) {
            [[unlikely]] __builtin_trap();
        }
#else
        assert(pairs.size() > 0 && pairs.size() % 2 == 0);
#endif
    }

    return SumOfDistancesFast(pairs.data(), pairs.size());
}
```

([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAGzSrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmABykAA6oCoRODB7evgHSaRmOAqHhUSyx8Um2mPbFDEIETMQEOT5%2BgTV1WY3NBKWRMXEJyQpNLW15nWN9A%2BWVIwCUtqhexMjsHOYAzGHI3lgA1CbbbgophifYJhoAgjt4VAxYVIcRACLYFnIA4jf3Zl2DH2XiOJzcogUShaV3%2BO1cjzhd0wqgIcQYh1oAmAhyEPgA8lR3ngZsDMAoAGJMMYQNAMMaY7GHABUpEOGQAXpgAPoERaHBioFEbFIEE5WO7/NEsFIGNHgzk8giHbCoxjKk7vdkEdAgEDoACezBYeGQ3JRaMEsMlAFYrHbBfgFKJiOgTDb3u7PXc6WMUSliIyjLiCUSSU0yQoIGNdSBzpdTr7lVijGzVZaxdtsIcLnhiAp%2BYLhZhRXCAOwS26HauHAD0tcOACUSwYNocCAgSSB/jXtUxHGbqdCCBB0%2BrjttPZPDlh9gQDSlMBBc/nFnqLerFuKezXHock/7A6O1YJDmAwJrtbHDcbTeaT3zjhWd73qzMB9yh3ERyuFAA6RUIH5TVLzHQQt22StXxrd87y/FplyYPN/0A4Cs0ODRjjMfxzH8HMkPzAC8C5ICsJtQ4zAnKctQ0CCoJrEwyy1WolCfSsHioF43k%2Bb4/juaC9wgc9EOQoiSLQ7NMNw3D8NE1CyIoqjL1o4C7XdCwvAYWg8AAa1qA0vS9Q5uW5aIvDoRwGF5YgmBSIDt0lQEWMwF8a3gn8CJQ4ilwkjCsJw7DZMI%2BTzHIyiQOnWiHIBbYESoVzGO9e5%2BJretDgAdUIBB207BRuxS6s0oDTA6XwepjwzJTp1nWh50XETV3XB86NcoriBKgQyqyCrxwirUYz1G9WDvDdT0YtxxqCrzxKqrUwL5aLezajrnkyAQGumnyJ0k/yZN/MSttCxS%2BowlrJQKw52oINYMTxFhCWJUkNkpakPNE9B%2ByYIC2X21CzvuJikXuNS7X2QxQBAVBRUFcJDI9OsG2KgA3ccwm0hgwmAf4UxxO6HvDQxnqpGkkyDHFmV/NlFV5KbuUVQshVUEUNWfC60oAFXxd58RAJsWyYNsAHcssOL8KloA1DhR/MslcnHLvJLxaqojDFprfgj2p5U8BVjRxUOHXwVpxU6wo/XDcsS8zGA1mq2ghWFCVjVLenX91LwIyAFopvdrCLEOLhDMghLAYuq6bodp3osSoGHmBA5MAnNxmhsgyszhQE9gTpO6WZhRrRirPQUT8EnDGdrWALuOQTBU4UYcEgq7uMJlRYJCGFIxj6LfHU9XrohiHBHGrkj2r8%2BD867cKhs8WQDZMHQBQ2WQBASr09BReVNAZToRPHDYVzSflt2Qa1S8u64NkzDZbY2UkGOJ6n0WvCIY2LgxS8Brjd%2Bu7dwHH97LBQcUJvzRl7nGVgPJqQKnAfGBg4Ij7YjvlcNkNU6pLl/HTd%2BEFsD/V7O1R2Y8/wpC8AoBApkBY6QgHjMMT1yQbSwYYRY/1Wozy8HPTAC8l6HDMsqcIXDRaXU0vvROK816uS/v3Rupxh7oUwfXFWF8b5shtGyMsD9u7P1fvIkqjCP7Ti/nA3%2BnluT1z/MgWIwAwjfVpmYjYzx7L/00UAz8ICEKGMga48ErlAGwJ/omAQDIcZU3AUNE0ZpRqZmwKQHxNY0ELgwSY%2BueicF4JrAQp2/4SFkIocgKhNDHoRmegw5JcDmHRzZmwjhXC2S8MOAgakosMSaXCM9BQzRJbEGEXgNg%2B5V55MPoEtEqgAx9gHPuIZWjUDtkFlDExGwRkqy/kQT8xBU5D2xFcCASiA5skvgHRKaSe79jgm4kcHi2BeNOLE6spMv4pyYGnNwwTDj3yzDEi6vZ4n1QILMzBCyUipLVrcoZh4xmmgmfSZUTAX7TN%2BXM5C3IAV6KWX4hMEJJmyOuBWeF/z/QaIkU0D87kwGxnaZc6B1zPk1juWi%2BBASoVkxCdeI0w0IkPhQTcmcJVaoJIgLi%2BZ/oUlXCOaPAgWTSHkOiJQ6hoZCmE3oQKxFyKyksMqbiIlpoxAS0OFQJCtB84XUQcGDs7UXKn0URWfZ19DjbAJRdGFr8XGms4aislP8cUIDNfap%2BLiSUXKgePCa1Ke7uvRca4AN9OUhu5XOPlzqvWcKBQA1KDYMlEOyVKmVBSCaRn5YmzA5SU3VlYYcd4rLwnaslnqughrfXgKkYPGRmz0Iup5Ao8%2BVqr5RqcYSsN9KMWMqxTOCtd421dzbaYkq5jLHWOWDlM1U7kDmNcI4qcmj6zpvFcQyVuT8lytzcUsJY6C1FvYuq8tt5RC0B1TWg1tSX4TKVhvWIOZiCoBRhiJ1mrr23v1YMqFYKgGQqCUySdAL1JGU7RYa1Pb10Ab9CMwMwHDH%2BMHaBowI9wNCqMZ6xdEHe2VK3RKnJ0q8myvurQopiqC1Ipw9gtV9bYxoEfd404WEzDEctVYMwZhgU8NQJ4XVyENTTgIF0lyxbdUkEOBAR10yt2HF5sRm2mjeyCRoPmR8XcuW9k0wyS8eqDWSbUwxJihxnJsV0zBcBLHRMTXY%2BYG1Tn%2BO9hjjGr%2Bdmk5Gy3fx9zTG9RebY24DjMdePefY1/VwtBo6h1uBwZYtBOA2l4H4DgWhSCoE4BNS2lh2SrHWCXQEPBSAEE0Al5YOkQA2g0H%2BDQ2EuAaAAJz%2BH8BoG0ZZJCSEvkljgkhUvlcy5wXgeUNClfK8sOAsAYCIBQKgHe9AyAUFpPNlIu94hgyMFwNrY2sBI1NJgAAangTAgt8SLjSyVmgtU4h5QgNEQb0QwgdM4CVp7zBiAGnxNEbQJUyvcF4NvNggh8RaQNINrAZlgDJxvXlAHpAsBtyMOIdLvB8DtQcHgFGcOMsohKi/TYGWW61EG9paINlPseCwIN8TPTXsJb4AYYAChjunfO4wenMhBAiDEOwKQXP5BKDUIN3QPXwYoGsNYfQeBoh5UgMsKG9Q4eexjJqUwuWLBmEwp7fElFPbvA%2BF8X4vAP1xGIHgLAcvvp2D%2B1kFwzxJh%2BEviEMIgwKjDEvoUNa2RPDtD0F7%2BocwhjxEvjbzHAhegTF93kUPtRbcR/GP0V38wPe2ET47vQMwWhB/dyH5YCgCsbAkIl5LA3UdDY4IcVQiR/Ce0CPuAwwZtt1bq7J3AhAZM7C4IsXg/2tDMNIFVmr%2BhOD9dICwarY20sZayxwEbIAxt94Z1N2bqwCAkIIOQFwZUSAW70Pwbn16%2BfSAP4LlQ6hy%2Bi9IILGyKR6cl44Cl0g0%2BTecHxC/DfhxUCvGr7X%2Bvm2cRm9atMIIAPAFs4gsJthu9e8JtlhV4mAsB4hvpesx8J9h8X8K959F9YDB8QBJAms/wmsyxthEgmsNBthtgmtJAzAbQbQmsR8OBtgy8Z9htxtUcB9eszBmDX8582D%2B9lhpYMhnBJAgA%3D) link with some example usages)

I think I should be able to make this example less repetitive while preserving the same safety properties, something like this:

```cpp
#include <span>

#define precondition(_cond) /* static or dynamic assert */

extern long SumOfDistancesFast(const long *, size_t) noexcept;

template<size_t Extent = std::dynamic_extent>
[[nodiscard]]
constexpr long SumOfDistances(std::span<const long, Extent> pairs) noexcept
{
    precondition(Extent == decltype(pairs)::extent);
    precondition(Extent == std::dynamic_extent || pairs.size() == Extent);
    precondition(pairs.size() > 0 && pairs.size() % 2 == 0);

    return SumOfDistancesFast(pairs.data(), pairs.size());
}
```

In this updated example, the `precondition` macro doesn't care whether I'm statically or dynamically asserting and it will return me an error as soon as possible. Is it possible to write it?

Comment: `Extent == decltype(pairs)::extent` This will always be true. `pairs.size() == Extent` This will *also* always be true for static extents. The only meaningful condition is checking if it is even and non-zero.

Comment: @NicolBolas fair, the first two might as well be `precondition(2 + 2 == 4)` as they are just restating the std::span API but writing them down here serves as both documentation and optimization hints. In both cases the compiler should be able to recognize that these are compile-time constant expressions and fold them away to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The `precondition` macro can be defined as

```
#define precondition(cond) \
if constexpr (requires { typename std::bool_constant<(cond)>; }) \
  static_assert(cond); \
else \
  assert(cond);
```

If the condition is a constant expression, which can be used as a non-type template argument, then use `static_assert`. Otherwise, a runtime `assert` check is used.

```
template<size_t Extent = std::dynamic_extent>
[[nodiscard]]
constexpr long SumOfDistances(std::span<const long, Extent> pairs) noexcept
{
    // With this:
    precondition(Extent == decltype(pairs)::extent);
    precondition(Extent == std::dynamic_extent || pairs.size() == Extent);
    precondition(pairs.size() > 0 && pairs.size() % 2 == 0);

    return SumOfDistancesFast(pairs.data(), pairs.size());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6xW6Waojo) (Clang does not seem to be able to determine constant expressions through the `requires`-clause, which seems to be a bug)